# Is it possible to have an auto-refresh while editing a markdown file with mdp?

Tags: console, markdown

`mdp` is a console viewer for Markdown files and I find it is a very helpful tool.

Is it though anyhow possible to make the tool/the console to auto-refresh so that I have immediate visual feedback while writing?

**UPDATE**

Indeed there's an according [feature request](https://github.com/visit1985/mdp/issues/114) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like [entr](https://github.com/clibs/entr) (Event Notify Test Runner) allows you to run arbitary commands when files change, would be a possible solution.

Comment: thank you! so following the examples from the docs, I tried: 1) run the command ```ls README.md | entr sh -c 'mdp'``` 2) change that ```README.md``` in a separate console => nothing happens. :-/

Comment: I'm not able to get it to automatically update display using `entr` - but if you press `r` in `mdp` it will automatically re-read the file.  Running `ls *.md | entr mdp /_` sort of works if you press `q` in the terminal running `entr` it will then respawn mdp when the file changes. hth

Comment: respawn did not work but the ```r``` is working for me so far.